magento2 i have to try to product grid custom column data pass
    define([
    'mage/adminhtml/grid'
], function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (config) {
        var selectedProducts = config.selectedProducts,
            categoryProducts = $H(selectedProducts),
            gridJsObject = window[config.gridJsObjectName],
            tabIndex = 1000;
        /**
         * Show selected product when edit form in associated product grid
         */
        $('bliss_products').value = Object.toJSON(categoryProducts);
        /**
         * Register Category Product
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {Object} element
         * @param {Boolean} checked
         */
        function registerCategoryProduct(grid, element, checked) {
            if (checked) {
                if (element.positionElement) {
                    element.positionElement.disabled = false;
                    categoryProducts.set(element.value, element.positionElement.value);
                }
            } else {
                if (element.positionElement) {
                    element.positionElement.disabled = true;
                }
                categoryProducts.unset(element.value);
            }
            $('bliss_products').value = Object.toJSON(categoryProducts);
            grid.reloadParams = {
                'selected_products[]': categoryProducts.keys()
            };
        }

        /**
         * Click on product row
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {String} event
         */
        function categoryProductRowClick(grid, event) {
            var trElement = Event.findElement(event, 'tr'),
                isInput = Event.element(event).tagName === 'INPUT',
                checked = false,
                checkbox = null;

            if (trElement) {
                checkbox = Element.getElementsBySelector(trElement, 'input');

                if (checkbox[0]) {
                    checked = isInput ? checkbox[0].checked : !checkbox[0].checked;
                    gridJsObject.setCheckboxChecked(checkbox[0], checked);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Change product position
         *
         * @param {String} event
         */
        function customerpricechange(event) {
            var element = Event.element(event);

            if (element && element.checkboxElement && element.checkboxElement.checked) {
                categoryProducts.set(element.checkboxElement.value, element.value);
                $('bliss_products').value = Object.toJSON(categoryProducts);
            }
        }

        function customerspecilpricechange(event) {
            var element = Event.element(event);

            if (element && element.checkboxElement && element.checkboxElement.checked) {
                categoryProducts.set(element.checkboxElement.value, element.value);
                $('bliss_products').value = Object.toJSON(categoryProducts);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Initialize category product row
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {String} row
         */
        function categoryProductRowInit(grid, row) {
            var checkbox = $(row).getElementsByClassName('checkbox')[0],
                customerprice = $(row).getElementsByClassName('input-text')[0];
                customerspecilprice = $(row).getElementsByClassName('input-text')[1];

            if (checkbox && customerprice) {
                checkbox.positionElement = customerprice;
                customerprice.checkboxElement = checkbox;
                customerprice.disabled = !checkbox.checked;
                customerprice.tabIndex = tabIndex++;
                Event.observe(customerprice, 'keyup', customerpricechange);
            }

             if (checkbox && customerspecilprice) {
                checkbox.positionElement = customerspecilprice;
                customerspecilprice.checkboxElement = checkbox;
                customerspecilprice.disabled = !checkbox.checked;
                customerspecilprice.tabIndex = tabIndex++;
                Event.observe(customerspecilprice, 'keyup', customerspecilpricechange);
            }
        }

        gridJsObject.rowClickCallback = categoryProductRowClick;
        gridJsObject.initRowCallback = categoryProductRowInit;
        gridJsObject.checkboxCheckCallback = registerCategoryProduct;

        if (gridJsObject.rows) {
            gridJsObject.rows.each(function (row) {
                categoryProductRowInit(gridJsObject, row);
            });
        }
    };
});

